# Exporting data using Essbase MDX for BSO

Tags: database, export, mdx, essbase

I'm trying to export a fairly large data from a BSO cube using MDX scripting to be imported in another BSO cube. I have tried calc script and report script but it takes a lot of time. My cube has only 4 dimensions-Accounts(dense),Years(sparse),Scenario(sparse) and Countries(Sparse).

The MDX script I'm using is below:

```
SELECT {[Years].[Jan],[Scenario].[Actual]} ON COLUMNS,
NonEmptysubset (Crossjoin({[Accounts].Levels(0).members},
({[Countries].Levels(0).members}))

ON ROWS From [Test.XXX];
```

Again this script is taking a lot of time, which it shouldn't. Can someone please tell me what is mistake I'm making in above? I want the data to be exported in less than a minute.
Thanks!

Comment: Crossjoin. Don't you use measures here?

Answer (score 0):

Change NonEmptysubset to NONEMPTYBLOCK

Answer (score 0):

try changing your query something like this.

```
SELECT {[Jan]} ON COLUMNS,
NonEmptysubset(Crossjoin(
{[Countries].Levels(0).members},
{[Accounts].Levels(0).members}))
ON ROWS From [Test.XXX];
where ([Actual])
```

try to keep the dense dimension at the end and add where clause to filter before it drills down to bottom of the required dims.